# Como hacer que un servicio/daemon no consuma tantos recursos

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, procesos-en-segundo-plano

estoy haciendo un programa sencillito, mi idea es controlar los archivos que tengo en descargas, y en caso de que vuelva a descargar un archivo repetido, este se sobrescriba automáticamente. Esto me viene bien ya que cuando quiero acceder a un fichero en concreto, en vez de ir al directorio *descargas* a buscarlo, voy a la plataforma donde se encuentra (moodle), ya que la organización que me ofrece es mas visual y cómoda. El caso es que este programa no será algo que me resuelva la vida, pero me hace ilusión introducirme en la automatización e ir toqueteando por mi cuenta.
Al grano;
Mi programa es este (lo estoy usando para testear)

```
 package gestor;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Gestor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File f = new File("/home/tarde/fich.txt");
        while(true) {
            System.setOut(new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f)), true));
            System.out.println("Hola");
        }
        

    }

}
```

Como veis, es la cosa mas simple del mundo, básicamente pongo un "hola" en un fichero constantemente.
Bien, la idea es que mi programa, esté leyendo constantemente la ruta de descargas, de forma que pueda detectar si se ha descargado un nuevo archivo, y hacer la acción necesaria. El problema viene aquí, y es que al implementar este programa como servicio en Ubuntu (también me ha pasado en Windows), consume demasiado, y llega a ralentizar el pc. De hecho os dejo esto por aquí para que veáis que es verdad:
[image: consumo proceso]

He aquí mi duda: me gustaría saber cuál es la forma correcta de implementar este programita. No se si es que estoy haciendo mal en hacer un bucle infinito, imagino que si, pero no se me ocurre otra forma de saber la cantidad de hay archivos que hay en todo momento en x directorio.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: creo que te va a ser util leer esto: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Comment: Pensando un poco mas, una forma de evitar que consuma tantos recursos es _cerrando_ las cosas que vas abriendo de forma adecuada. En esta forma de trabajo, estas creando muchas instancias de objetos que hacen IO _sin cerrarlas_ que van a ser cerradas _mucho después_, cuando corra el `GarbageCollector`. Podrías utilizar `try with resources` para asegurarte de que los recursos que vas abriendo se vayan cerrando. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html. Igualmente deberias mirar lo que comenté antes para no tener que estar monitoreando "a pie".